# Can I create a Visual Studio project file from files on a server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have access to a working ASP.NET MVC 4 website through FTP but do not have the Visual Studio project file. Using these files can I create a Visual Studio project file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to all the class files, views etc but are just missing the solution/project file then technically you can wrap them up in an empty project but it would still be a **different** project.

If you only have access to the published output (the views and JavaScript) then in short the answer is no, not without trying to reverse engineer the dll which I have heard is possible but have never tried myself.